# Some of your tests did a full page reload - error when running Jasmine tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm running into an issue where when I run my tests on Jasmine, I get this error below.  The problem is, it seems to happen when I try to execute a certain amount of tests.  It doesn't seem to be tied to a particular test, as if I comment out some, the tests pass.  If I uncomment some tests, the error appears.  If I comment out ones that were uncommented before, they all pass again.  (ie if I have red, green, blue and orange test and it fails, I comment out orange and blue it passes, then I uncomment blue and orange it fails again, but if I comment out red and green it passes again).

> Chrome 41.0.2272 (Mac OS X 10.10.1) ERROR   Some of your tests did a
>   full page reload! Chrome 41.0.2272 (Mac OS X 10.10.1): Executed 16 of
>   29 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.108 secs / 0.092 secs)

I'm stumped as to what is going on.  The more tests I add, that's when this becomes an issue.  Has anyone encountered this before?  I have no idea what could be causing it, as nothing in any of my tests do any kind of redirection, and they all pass universally on another persons machine.

Comment: Can you add some of your tests to the question to get a feel for the issue.

Comment: As the error message states, your tests are causing a full page load. You should be trying to figure out why the page load is happening.  The tests must be navigating to a new location.

Comment: Does your app use ui-router, by any chance?

Comment: I see you're using Chrome. Does the same thing happen in Firefox or PhantomJS?

Comment: @Manube No I am not.  And Michal It happens in Firefox as well, yes.

Comment: I too have the same issue. If you have got the solution, could you please let me know. Its been more than a week, but still having the same issue.

Comment: Having the same issue.  No solutions anywhere.  I have 8 describe blocks in one test, I get the full page reload, if I comment out any of the 8 describes (reducing the count to 7) it works.

Comment: @MichalCharemza for me it's the case - it happens on chrome but on firefox tests are going through well. Do you know what might be a reason?

Answer (score 50):

In my case the problem was that in my source code I had code directly setting the *href* on the *location* object, like *window.location.href = 'somewhere';*

In my specs I set up a *onbeforeunload* listener that just returns a string instead of allowing the redirect to take place:

```
beforeAll(() => {
  window.onbeforeunload = () => 'Oh no!';
});
```

Answer (score 30):

I suppose you are using `window.location` somewhere in your targeted code. In order to pass it just create a spy for the `window.onbeforeunload`

Example:

```
window.onbeforeunload = jasmine.createSpy();
```

Or even better use `$window` instead, and this will not happen.

Comment: It worked, but with an argument inside createSpy - just a string.

Answer (score 20):

Make sure that your tests are properly isolating all modules under test with mocks/spies.  The behavior you are seeing says to me that your tests are not truly running in isolation - they are changing some state somewhere that will trigger a reload.

Comment: I actually found the place after offering the bounty. And yes, you are right on the money. In my case the reload was triggered after a certain amount of tests for some reason - because of a pending http-httprequest to an external system that timed out exactly between test 13 and 14... ;)

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways this error can happen.

If your component has a **form** element, this might be the cause.

Whenever a button on the form is clicked, this error can happen, even tho your component contains no navigation logic.

Comment: Thank you very much! This answer just saved my day! Turns out the buttons within <form> element are specified to type="submit" (by default). After changing them to type="button", it solves the problem.

Comment: Man, you just saved my evening!

Comment: This answer saved me a TON of time. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I recently encountered this error with Karma 0.13.12. I upgraded to Karma 0.13.14 and my tests work again. The problem for me (and probably also for @mqklin) was related to https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1656 and https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/945.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was upgrading Karma from 1.4.0 to 1.4.1 and changing the maximumSpecCallbackDepth in my jasmine.js file from 20 to 100.

Comment: Please reformat this answer and expand it a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

creating a spy on the function which has the window.location / reload fixed the issue for me

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have used `window.location = "some url"` in your code;
Faced similar problem, and solved by using the below changes.

Replaced window.location in the code with,

```
window.location.assign("some url");
```

Do the below in unit test:

```
spyOn(window.location, "assign").and.callFake(() => {
    // Dummy assign call - so that your actual call will be faked and the reload will not happen. 
});
```

Comment: seems as nice suggestion but I got 'assign is not declared writable or has no setter'

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce amount of `describe` sections or completely remove them. I don't know why, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to make sure that modules are not being loaded twice. In my case, I had an AngularJS module file -e.g., `auth.controller.js` which contents were already bundled in a `core.js` file. Once I excluded the bundled files on karma, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `setTimeout(() => window.location.replace('/'), 10);`
I used below code in my unit test and it worked for me.

```
spyOn(global, 'setTimeout');
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it was ng-submit callback, which doesn't call "event.preventDefault()" and the browser reloads page. Mocking $location doesn't help in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

According to angularjs documentation you should inject the $window module to be able to solve the testability issue you get. If you really want to do a full page refresh while routing, which will reload the whole application. But anyway...

**So for example in component**

```
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window**) 
 {

      $scope.doRerouteWithPageReload = function() {
       return this.$window.location.href = "/myUrl";
 };
```

And then **in your test-file** you import $window to the test-controller your way, then where you assign spies you can do something like this:

```
$window = { location: {href: jasmine.createSpy() };
```

And then the actual test is something like this:

```
expect($window.location.href).toBe("/myUrl");
```

[Angularjs documentation for reading more about $window.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window)

Answer (score -1):

It will solve this Karma redirect error!

```
var html = '<script type="text/javascript">';
html += 'window.location = "' + urlToRedirect +'"';
html += '</script>';
$( '.wrapper' ).append( html );
```